# css button text and button background different opacity

Tags: html, css

hopefully you can help with a simple question about CSS. I'm trying to make a button (doesn't need to be html class button) with a transparent background and an outline with text that does not have the same opacity as the button. That is, the text should remain at a different opacity than the button. Is this possible?

My attempt at a fiddle to solve this here - http://jsfiddle.net/9jXYt/

CSS:

```
#xxx {
  outline:white solid 0.5px;
  /*opacity: 0.2; */
  background-color: rgba(255,0,0,0.2);
  padding: 6px 8px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  color: black;
  font-weight: bold;
  border: none;
  margin: 0;
  /*box-shadow: 0px 2px 3px #444;*/
}

#xxx:hover {
   opacity: 0.9; 
}

#fff {
    font-family: helvetica, arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 19pt;
    opacity: 1 !important;
    color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5) !important;
}
```

HTML:
    `<button id="xxx"><div id="fff">This is a test</div></button>`

Thanks in advance for any hints.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`opacity` is inherited by children and can't be reversed, so use `rgba` on the parent as well. E.g.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>

#xxx {
  outline:white solid 0.5px;
  padding: 6px 8px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  color:rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
  font-weight: bold;
  border: none;
  margin: 0;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  font-family: helvetica, arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 19pt;
}

#xxx:hover {
   background: rgba(0,0,0,0.4); 
   color:rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<button id="xxx">This is a test</button>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: That works great - thanks for clarifying. One minor follow-up - I tried to edit your fiddle (that always disturbs me to say) to get the border or outline to support rgba(x,y,z,a) - but that doesn't seem to work - is there a work around?

Comment: Do you mean something like this? `border: 5px solid rgba(3,66,22,0.5);`

Answer (score 4):

I think the secret to what you're trying to do is to use transparent colors rather than opacity.

```
#xxx {
  outline:white solid 0.5px;
  padding: 6px 8px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0, .25);
  color: black;
  font-weight: bold;
  border: none;
  margin: 0;
}

#xxx:hover {
   background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.30);
}

#fff {
    font-family: helvetica, arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 19pt;
    color: rgba(0,0,0,.25);
}
#fff:hover {   
   color: rgba(0,0,0,.6);
}
```

I've adapted your fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/harveyramer/8pymY/

Answer (score 1):

```
#xxx:hover {
  background-color: rgba(255,0,0,0.9);  
}
```

By setting your opacity you are affecting everything in it.

Answer (score 0):

As *ralph.m* said,
`opacity is inherited by children and can't be reversed, so use rgba on the parent as well.` In case you need an **example**, here is an **edited** jsfiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/9jXYt/3/

Good luck!