# How to set opacity only on button text color without rgba?

Tags: css, frontend

something like:

```
    background-color: #000;
    color: #fff;
    color-opacity: 0.5;
```

rgba unused, because all color in hex format.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [css button text and button background different opacity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21511641/css-button-text-and-button-background-different-opacity)

Comment: @B001 designer says

Comment: You could also convert [HEX to RGBA](http://hex2rgba.devoth.com/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the [8-digit HEX code](https://css-tricks.com/8-digit-hex-codes/) color like this:

```css
div {
  background-color: #000;
  color: #ffffff80;
}
```

```html
<div>text</div>
```

Comment: Woah, I never knew 8-digit hexcodes were even a thing! Thanks for this! Mind blown.

Answer (score 1):

You could use an extra HTML element.

```css
.button {
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #000;
}

.button > .text {
  opacity: 0.5;
}
```

```html
<button class="button">
  <span class="text">
    Click me.
  </span>
</button>
```

Comment: Simple and elegant!

Comment: Yes, i know this way, but exist only css way?

Comment: Without RGBA, I am not aware of no such thing. I suppose you could use JavaScript to convert the HEX value of the color of your text into an RGBA value, but that would be neither elegant and this is probably not what you want.

Comment: @AleksandrMaybach - before you use an extra HTML element you should use `rgba`. You can convert hex to rgb.

Comment: Not using RGBA is part of the question.